# Application Deployment [.NET 2.0 + Access 2007 Runtime]

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I have created an app that needs proper deployment now.

The application is written in C#/.NET.

The application uses old database (access 2007 runtime) and is built on .NET 2.0 framework.

How can I properly deploy the application with a single installer, assuming that system doesn't have .NET 2.0 and access 2007 runtime?

Comment: Use the package wizard and run it from your installer.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb501030%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing this as follow:

1. Create MSI or EXE installer for your application. You can use [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).
2. Create bootsrapter that checks if .NET Framework is installed. If not: install it and run main instalation packege (created in point 1). You can use [DotnetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/).
3. You should also add [Access 2007 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4438) to your bootsratper that will be installed when MS Office is not present on Client machine.

DotnetInstaller gives you ability to create one-file installation.

Comment: tyyyy

alternatively i am using

Advance Installer 9.2 [did the job]